# Help with launching wither skulls

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I am working on a datapack for a server. It's a datapack with custom swords and I have 1 sword done already and I'm trying to make another one the wither sword. An ability you would expect it to have is shooting wither skulls so I watched a thing on how to apply motion onto entities based on the place you are looking and it's all good and working except for on the y - for some reason, the y motion doesn't work at all.

```
    tp ~ ~1 ~
    execute store result score @s mx1 run data get entity @s Pos[0] 10000
    execute store result score @s my1 run data get entity @s Pos[1] 10000
    execute store result score @s mz1 run data get entity @s Pos[2] 10000
    
    tp @s ^ ^ ^0.1
    
    execute store result score @s mx2 run data get entity @s Pos[0] 10000
    execute store result score @s my2 run data get entity @s Pos[1] 10000
    execute store result score @s mz2 run data get entity @s Pos[2] 10000
    
    execute store result entity @s Motion[0] double 0.0015 run scoreboard players operation @s mx2 -= @s mx1
    execute store result entity @s Motion[1] double 0.0015 run scoreboard players operation @s my2 -= @s my1
    execute store result entity @s Motion[2] double 0.0015 run scoreboard players operation @s mz2 -= @s mz1
    
    
    tag @s add motion_added
```

This code is executed once for any wither skull I summon with a certain tag this is the only thing that really matters but just for maybe some more info the command I use to trigger this is:
`execute as @e[tag=shotskull,tag=!motion_added] at @s rotated as @p run function vengeance:applymotion`

I simply don't see how this could make it so only y doesn't work. The other ones work completely fine.

Comment: did you check afterwards (e.g. print the Motion to chat) whether the Motion has been properly updated? Because I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work, either, maybe skulls are weird and also need their power set or something.

Comment: i just did that and it seems like it was makeing it so high that it couldent handle it like it made the y things like -10000 when i was barely even looking down it seems to be a problem with the scaleing

Comment: sounds about right. since you're scaling the position by 10000 and are only scaling it down by 0.0015 instead of 0.0001, which makes it 15 times higher I guess. :D So it works now?